# Trying to connect to an SQL Server 2000 database through ODBC with C, problems on SQLConnect

Tags: c, sql-server, database, odbc

I'm having trouble connecting to an SQL Server 2000 database using C. The program compiles but I get an error when connecting to the database. More specifically, "resultado" gets a value of -1.
This is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <sqlext.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SQLHANDLE environmentHandle;
    SQLHANDLE connectionHandle;

    //Connecting to the Database
    SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &environmentHandle);
    SQLSetEnvAttr(environmentHandle, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (void*) SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);
    SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, environmentHandle, &connectionHandle);
    SQLSetConnectAttr(connectionHandle, SQL_LOGIN_TIMEOUT,(void*)  5, 0);
    SQLCHAR serverName[60]; strcpy((char*) serverName,"SERVERSUCURSAL\0");
    SQLCHAR userName[60];   strcpy((char*) userName, "sa\0");
    SQLCHAR passWord[60];   strcpy((char*) passWord, "syntelsol\0");
    SQLRETURN resultado = SQLConnect(connectionHandle,serverName, strlen((char*)serverName), userName, 
         strlen((char*)userName), passWord, strlen((char*)passWord));

    //Creamos las sentencias
    SQLHANDLE statementHandle; 

    //Liberamos las handles 
    SQLDisconnect(connectionHandle);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, connectionHandle);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, environmentHandle);

    return 0;
}
```

This is what the database looks like . The server name is likely SERVERSUCURSAL:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDzQp.png
[image: Databases]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you pass as ServerName to SQLConnect should be the name of a Data Source (DSN) which you need to create in the ODBC Administrator. It cannot just be the name of your SQL Server machine/database etc. Open ODBC Administrator and create a data source for MS SQL Server which points to your server.

BTW, you don't need to end all your strings with an extra NUL character either - not that it makes a difference here.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Can I know why I don't need the NUL character to mark the end of the name?